# Selenium: Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Selenium and python in general, I am following a tutorial but I keep running into this issue where it says "Ran 0 tests in 0.000s" even though I have tests outlined.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import page # a file that I created

class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\\Users\\paulk\\Desktop\\Selenium")
self.driver.get("http://www.python.org")
driver = self.driver

    def test_example(self): #if any method starts with "test_"
        print("Test")
        assert True
    
    def not_a_test(self):
        print("this will not print")
    
    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
unittest.main()
```

I tried renaming my test method so that it starts with "test" and the issue is still happening.

Comment: you need to fix the indentation, it matters very much in python

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure your code appears exactly as you actually have it. The code that you show has mulitple syntax errors due to wrong indentation; we cannot fix that for you because different indentation could mean different things. Aside from that, please read [ask] and try to communicate more clearly. "but I keep running into this issue where it says "Ran 0 tests in 0.000s" even though I have tests outlined." - this cannot be understood: **what is "it"**?

Comment: Make sure to explain clearly: where is the file with this code? How exactly do you try to run the tests? **Exactly** what output do you get (copy and paste it out of the terminal, and format it like code)? Finally, read [mre] and try to isolate the problem. For example, is there still a problem if you *don't* try to use Selenium? Can you make it run any tests at all? Have you tried to use `unittest` before? (We aren't very interested in what your tutorial says to do, because we can't see it and aren't following it.)